# general protection error stopping my prod container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kernel

I started having a general protection in the last days which results in my container restarting, thus, disrupting the service, whenever the general protection error happens, i can see in the cloudwatch monitoring charts, that there some sudden small spikes that happened minutes before, i don't know if it is related or not, but wanted to mention it.

This is the error :

```
kernel: [10083817.146880] traps: node[17179] general protection ip:7f918c073529 sp:7ffcb10f0430 error:0 in libc-2.24.so[7f918c03f000+195000]
```

I'm using ubuntu 16 and Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

Comment: Where is the rest of it?

Comment: that's the whole error in the kernel log file.

Comment: @MichaelHampton do you have any idea ?